# How to pass Zeeplein input field value to spark program

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

`Jar` file are running in zeppelin via using Hard code of emp-id.

```
%spark
var empObj= new Emp()
empObj.MainMethod("12")
```

I have create a text field in zeppelin.

```
%spark z.input("emp-id")
```

How i pass the `text field` emp-id value to `jar` file program.
After submit of emp-id, i want to execute the `jar` file program.

Please suggest.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as argument to your method :

```
%spark
var empObj= new Emp()
empObj.MainMethod(z.input("emp-id"))
```

See [documentation](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/notebooks-and-dashboards/notebooks/zep-notebooks/dynamic-form.html#using-programming-language).